# How to overwrite/edit XML element in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am making a program that takes information from the user and saves it as an `XML` file. The information includes a name, and other details. I would like to be able to allow the user to enter the same name, and instead of a new element being created with the same name, it would overwrite the existing element with the new values entered.

I hope that made sense, but in case not an example would be if I entered the name John Smith, and age 250. Clearly I would like to change the typo, so I would do it again to enter John Smith, age 25. When I do this a new element is created to add another John Smith, is there a way to just edit/overwrite the existing element? I'll post the code I use to create the `XML` if it is any help!

Thanks in advance!

```
XDocument Xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("XMLFile"));
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            Xdoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
        }
        else
        {
            Xdoc = new XDocument();
        }

        XElement xml = new XElement("Member");
        xml.Add(new XElement("Name", txtName.Text));
        xml.Add(new XElement("Age", txtAge.Text));
        xml.Add(new XElement("Nationality", txtNationality.Text));
        xml.Add(new XElement("EmailAddress", txtEmailAddress.Text));
        xml.Add(new XElement("ContactNumber", txtContactNumber.Text));


        if (Xdoc.Descendants().Count() > 0)
        {
            Xdoc.Descendants().First().Add(xml);
        }
        else
        {
            Xdoc.Add(xml);
        }

        Xdoc.Save(filepath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the elements you want and set their value using their `.Value` property.

Note that there is a large bug in your code. When the document is initially empty, you add the first `Member` as the root element of your document, but after that, you add all the additional `Members` as *children of that first member*.

Here is the correct code to do the update and also add new members correctly.

```
XDocument Xdoc;

if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
{
    Xdoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
}
else
{
    Xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Members"));
}

XElement member = Xdoc
    .Descendants("Member")
    .FirstOrDefault(m => (string) m.Element("Name") == name);

if (member != null)
{
    member.Element("Age").Value = age;
    member.Element("Nationality").Value = age;
    member.Element("EmailAddress").Value = age;
    member.Element("ContactNumber").Value = age;
}
else
{
    XElement newMember = new XElement("Member",
        new XElement("Name", name),
        new XElement("Age", age),
        new XElement("Nationality", nationality),
        new XElement("EmailAddress", email),
        new XElement("ContactNumber", contactNumber)
        );

    Xdoc.Descendants("Members").First().Add(newMember);
}

Xdoc.Save(filepath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is.  When you load your xml, create two divergent paths of action based on whether that name exists, then merge the paths back at saving the xml:

```
XDocument Xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("XMLFile"));
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
{
     Xdoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
}
else
{
     Xdoc = new XDocument();
}

var existing = Xdoc.Descendants("Member").FirstOrDefault(m => m.Element("Name")?.Value == txtName.Text);

if (existing != null) //name existed in xml
{
      existing.Element("Age").Value = txtAge.Text;
      //....
      //....
}
else
{
      XElement xml = new XElement("Member");
      xml.Add(new XElement("Name", txtName.Text));
      xml.Add(new XElement("Age", txtAge.Text));
      xml.Add(new XElement("Nationality", txtNationality.Text));
      xml.Add(new XElement("EmailAddress", txtEmailAddress.Text));
      xml.Add(new XElement("ContactNumber", txtContactNumber.Text));

      if (Xdoc.Descendants().Count() > 0)
      {
          Xdoc.Descendants().First().Add(xml);
      }
      else
      {
          Xdoc.Add(xml);
      }
}

Xdoc.Save(filepath));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `XElement.SetElementValue(element, value)`.

Example:

```
xml.SetElementValue("Age", 25);
```

Another way you could go about this, which sounds like an overkill in this case is this:
How about storing the elements names and their values in a HashMap first, and then iterating through the HashMap and creating the XML elements. And reverse the process when someone is editing a value. So whenever someone makes an edit, you dump your elements in a HashMap, update your element value, and then recreate the xml elements.

Comment: I was looking for the values to be entered through a text box, sorry I should have mentioned that. I have it sorted now though, thanks anyway! :)